# Python - GAE - Script loop consuming much memory

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory, urlfetch

I am using the following script to create some rss snapshots (just saying).

The script runs on a backend and I am having some very heave ever increasing memory consumption.

```
class StartHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @ndb.toplevel
    def get(self):
        user_keys = User.query().fetch(1000, keys_only=True)
        if not user_keys:
            return
        logging.info("Starting Process of Users")
        successful_count = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        for user_key in user_keys:
            try:
                this_start_time = time.time()
                statssnapshot = StatsSnapShot(parent=user_key,
                                        property=get_rss(user_key.id())
                                        )
                #makes a urlfetch
                statssnapshot.put_async()
                successful_count += 1               
            except:
                pass
        logging.info("".join(("Processed: [",
                            str(successful_count),
                            "] users after [",
                            str(int(time.time()-start_time)),
                            "] secs")))
        return
```

**EDIT**

Here is also the rss functions lets say:

```
def get_rss(self, url):
        try:
            result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
            if not result.status_code == 200:
                logging.warning("Invalid URLfetch")
                return
        except urlfetch.Error, e:
            logging.warning("".join("Fetch Failed to get ",url," with",e))
            return
        content = result.content #Around 500 - 200KB
        reobj = re.compile(r'(?<=")[0-9]{21}(?=")')
        user_ids = reobj.findall(content)
        user_ids = set(user_ids)#set to fail if something is not unique
        return user_ids
```

The script runs ok, but as the Users become more the script consumes more and more memory. 
Coming from C I don't know how to manipulate memory and variables in Python that efficient.

For example I know that if a varible in python is not referenced again the garbage collector frees the memeory used for that variable, but then what seems to be my case and where am I doing it wrong?

How can I optimize this script **not** to have an ever **increasing** memory usage, but only consume the memory **required** for **each** user process?

Comment: I didn't spot any _obvious_ memory leak in your code snippet, but 1/ I have no experience with GAE and 2/ there are parts of the code you did not submit (specially "StatsSnapShot"). 
Just a couple hints wrt/ being more pythonic:
- `logging.warning("".join("Fetch Failed to get ",url," with",e))` => `logging.exception("Fetch Failed to get %s with %s", url, e)`
- `set(someseq)` will NOT 'fail if something is not unique' 
- **never** ever use a bare except clause (at least use logging.exception to have some feedback)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Meaning that will fail was typo, meant not douplicate.

Comment: Did use_cache=False work as expected?

Comment: @tesdal yes man everything ok. Give me some time and I ll validate the answer after some tests. Also disabled the memcache.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it! The get_rss is also a good candidate for ndb async, either as a callback to query.map, or batched as barriers. You can have 100 simultaneous API calls which enables you to make it noticeably faster if backend is mainly waiting for urlfetches now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NDB adds automatic caching, which is usually very convenient. You have in memory cache and memcached, and you can set policies for them.

When making a put, you can provide [context options](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/functions#context_options), and I suspect that the following would work for you:

```
statssnapshot.put_async(use_cache=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem and saved a lot of resources. I also disabled memcache which also improved things a lot. A small thing to say is that on the dev server still it get's loads of memory but on the production works fine.

Comment: Dev server has memcached emulation and uses sqllite, not external services so you get more memory usage. Regarding async, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async is worth a read.