# Cost efficient architecture for a lot of URL Fetch Requests on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

What would be the most cost efficient architecture on GAE to handle a lot of concurrent URL Fetch Requests? (Python)

I am talking of hundreds of thousands concurrent API Requests.

To do it with task queues and synchronous URL Fetch requests doesn't work, as the latency due to waiting for the response is to high and a lot of instances will be started.

With asynchronous URL fetches I have the problem, that the memory is way to small to handle the responses on one instance, so that it crashes.

How would a general cost efficient architecture for this look like on appengine?
Really appreciate any advise!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thoughts. I started a backend and improved my mermory with async writes and disabling context cache and memcache. Also a backend might be what you need in a operation of thousands of fetches etc because you can manage how much memory it can have, and you are not affected by the 10 minute limit of the taskqueue.

I don't know if it helps but my issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439626/python-gae-script-loop-consuming-much-memory) and solved.